# Freeing an object in an STL vector

Tags: c++, object, memory-leaks, stl

I have the following example to free an object in an STL vector.

```
#include <map>
#include <string>


using namespace std;

class Test
{
   public:
      char*  name;
      int id;
      Test(char* n, int i);
};

Test::Test(char* n, int i)
{
   name = n;
   id = i;
}


int main ()
{
        Test* t = new Test("hi", 5);

        vector<Test> v;
        v.insert(v.end(), *t);

        for(vector<Test>::iterator it = v.begin(); it != v.end(); it++)
        {
                if (it->id == 5)
                {
                        Test* ptr = &*it;
                        v.erase(it);
                        delete ptr;
                        break;
                }
        }

        return 0;
}
```

Which, according to what I have been researching, should be the right way to do this. However, valgrind gives me this complaint:

```
==7404== Invalid free() / delete / delete[]
==7404==    at 0x4A05130: operator delete(void*) (vg_replace_malloc.c:244)
==7404==    by 0x400FD2: __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<Test>::deallocate(Test*, unsigned long) (new_allocator.h:94)
==7404==    by 0x401004: std::_Vector_base<Test, std::allocator<Test> >::_M_deallocate(Test*, unsigned long) (stl_vector.h:133)
==7404==    by 0x401045: std::_Vector_base<Test, std::allocator<Test> >::~_Vector_base() (stl_vector.h:119)
==7404==    by 0x40109C: std::vector<Test, std::allocator<Test> >::~vector() (stl_vector.h:272)
==7404==    by 0x400998: main (test.cc:46)
==7404==  Address 0x4C58070 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 16 free'd
==7404==    at 0x4A05130: operator delete(void*) (vg_replace_malloc.c:244)
==7404==    by 0x40098A: main (test.cc:41)
```

And there is memory leak. What is the right way to do this?

Comment: Your vector contains `Test` not `Test*`, so are copying the contents of the pointer into the vector, there is nothing to `delete` from the vector.

Comment: I know. that's why I inserted *t, not t

Comment: `*t` dereferences the pointer and then you are copying a `Test` not a `Test *`.

Comment: so basically I should delete t after inserting and not worry about when erasing from the vector?

Comment: None of those pointers should be pointers.

Comment: People coming from other languages believe they must use `new` to create objects.  That's not true in C++.  The manuals for the other languages also say that in C++ it's really difficult to remember to `delete` everything you got from `new`, but the secret is that *you don't have to get everything from `new`, and if you avoid `new` you can avoid forgetting a `delete`*.

Comment: @chris I just wrote this code to pose a question for educational purposes. I just want to learn more about C++.

Comment: @MaxLybbert same goes for you

Comment: I can understand trying to learn more about C++.  And, for educational purposes, I'll repeat that there's no need to call `new` nearly as often as in other languages; it has a very different meaning in C++ than it has in Java, Python, C#, etc.  Removing the call to `new` would also remove the (incorrect) call to `delete` and the rigamarole with the pointer manipulation.  And would get rid of the memory leak that freaks out Java, Python, C#, etc. programmers.

Comment: You'll certainly need to learn about pointers, but for what it's worth, I've never seen code in production that calls `new`, immediately dereferences the pointer, and then needs to find the address of the resulting reference in order to call `delete`.  As long as you remember to store the result of dereferencing the pointer into a reference, you're guaranteed that it will work.  But nobody goes through those kinds of contortions; they simply keep the pointer around and remember to dereference it as needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's the same old rule as always

> every `new` shall be accompanied by exactly one `delete`

In your case the only time you call `new` is to allocate an instance of `Test` (and it's not clear why you're doing that at all, but let's ignore that). Then you insert a *copy* of that object into the `vector`; you *did not* allocate memory for the inserted object. So there's no need to call `delete` on memory managed by the `vector`.

On the other hand, you are leaking memory because you never called `delete` on the memory you did allocate. Add a

```
delete t;
```

in your code somewhere after you're done using `t`

---

Now, if your vector was declared as `vector<Test *>` instead, you'd need to manually `delete` the elements before removing them from the vector. But you should always be using `vector<unique_ptr<Test>>` (or some other smart pointer, or [`boost::ptr_vector`](http://www.boost.org/libs/ptr_container/doc/ptr_vector.html)) anyway if you need a vector of pointers, in which case the manual calls are `delete` will not be necessary.

Comment: Thank you. In the future, Im inserting the pointer to the object into the vector instead.

Comment: @Squall I added to the answer

Comment: if i store the object instead of the pointer, would the copied object stored inside the STL stay on the stack or the heap?

Comment: @Squall Depends on where the *pointed to* object is to begin with. In your example, if you were to insert `t`, instead of `*t`, the object would be on the heap (since it was allocated via `new`)

Comment: So both copies of the object would be on the heap in that case?

Comment: @Squall There are no 2 copies in that case, copying a pointer does not mean the pointed to memory gets duplicated. You just have two pointers that point to the same memory address.

Answer (score 4):

> Test* t = new Test("hi", 5);

You are leaking this object.  You are storing a *copy* of the object into the `vector`, but you are not freeing the original object afterwards.

> v.insert(v.end(), *t);

Use `v.push_back(*t)` instead.

> if (it->id == 5);

The semicolon is erroneous.  You need to remove it.

> Test* ptr = &*it;
>   v.erase(it);
>   delete ptr;

The `erase()` is fine, but the `delete` is not.  You are not storing objects allocated with `new` in your `vector`, so you should not be trying to `delete` them at all. You are trying to free memory that you do not own.

With that said, you have two choices:

1. store pointers in the `vector`:

   ```
   int main ()
   {
       Test* t = new Test("hi", 5);

       vector<Test*> v;
       v.push_back(t);

       for(vector<Test*>::iterator it = v.begin(); it != v.end(); ++it)
       {
           Test* ptr = *it;
           if (ptr->id == 5)
           {
               v.erase(it);
               delete ptr;
               break;
           }
       }

       return 0;
   }
   ```
2. don't store pointers in the vector:

   ```
   int main ()
   {
       /*
       Test *t = new Test("hi", 5);

       vector<Test> v;
       v.push_back(*t);

       delete t; // don't forget this!
       */

       vector<Test> v;
       v.push_back(Test("hi", 5));

       for(vector<Test>::iterator it = v.begin(); it != v.end(); ++it)
       {
           if (it->id == 5)
           {
               v.erase(it);
               break;
           }
       }

       return 0;
   }
   ```

FYI, you might consider using `std::find_if()` instead of a manual loop:

```
struct IsId
{
    int _id;
    IsId(int id) : _id(id) {}
    bool operator()(const Test &src) const { return (src.id == _id); }
};
```

```
vector<Test>::iterator it = find_if(v.begin(), v.end(), IsId(5));
if (it != v.end())
{
    v.erase(it);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[vector::erase](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/erase/) :

> Removes from the vector either a single element (position) or a range of elements ([first,last)).
>
> This effectively reduces the container size by the number of elements removed, which are destroyed.

So you have to just use the erase function. You dont need to use the pointer and delete.

And be aware that when you insert your new instance into vector:

```
v.insert(v.end(), *t);
```

The class is copy constructed again in vector so you are left with two separate instances one in `t` and one in `v[0]`.

Answer (score 2):

The right way to write your code in sane C++ is like this:

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<Test> v { Test(""hi", 5) };

}   // returns 0, frees all allocated resources
```